# Join Skype or Teams meeting using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, skype-for-business, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-teams

I wanted to know whether Microsoft Graph API provides an endpoint through which we can join both teams and skype scheduled meetings? I can see the teams api to create or schedule meetings but I don't see an api to join a scheduled meeting via meeting_url? Also I don't see any support for skype for business. Can someone provide me a definitive answer on these queries?

Comment: did you get an api to join the meeting using URL?

Answer (score 1):

The accurate and definite answer is No. MS does not provide any graph API that helps you to join a meeting.

What you can do is either join a meeting using Client Object ClientAgent.initialize and use .join() mehtod using ClientAgent to connect to meetign using Joinweburl getting from the graph API response.
Or
You can use `windows.open(response.joinwebURL)`
to get and connect to the meeting.

For ACS configuration please follow
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/quickstarts/voice-video-calling/get-started-teams-interop?pivots=platform-web
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, yes.

On the calendar event object there is a property , [that object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/onlinemeetinginfo?view=graph-rest-1.0) will have the joinUrl e.g.

```
"onlineMeeting": {
  "joinUrl": "https://teams.microsoft.com/l/meetup-join/19%3mymeetingdetails
}
```